# Finding the longest possible palindrome of any given list

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment where given a string that I then convert to string, I should find the longest possible palindrome of said list and output how many characters I had to remove from the list to achieve that goal.

My current code is as follows:

```
solve(X) :-
    string2List(X).

string2List(Input) :-
        string_codes(Input,Output),
        palchecker(Output,0).

palchecker(Input,LengthRest):-
    palindrome(PermuteList),
    is_permutation(Input,PermuteList),
    write(LengthRest).

palindrome(L):- reverse(L, L).

is_permutation(Xs, Ys) :-
  msort(Xs, Sorted),
  msort(Ys, Sorted).
```

As one can see I can handle lists that are already palindromes without issue. The issue is how to proceed when a list is not an palindrome but that a palindrome can be constructed from it by removing X amount of characters.

I previously used permutations instead of `is_permutation` and I managed to get it working (with some additional code). However the problem with that approach was that it was taking way too long of a time. The algorithm should be able to manage lists of upward 1000 characters in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Define "removing characters". Do you mean only removing from the beginning and end of the list, e.g., from `[a, b, c, c, b, d]` removing `a` and `d` to get the palindrome `[b, c, c, b]`, or removing from anywhere, e.g, from `[b, c, a, d, c, b]` removing the `a` and `d` in the middle to get the palindrome `[b, c, c, b]`?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that, it could be characters from any position in the list, so it's your latter suggestion that is correct.

Comment: I'm surprised `permutation/2` took longer than `is_permutation/2`.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing N items from the input list (N in 0..length_of_input) using `select/3` and then apply your algorithm.

Something like this:

```
string2List(Input, Output1, ToRemove) :-
        string_codes(Input,Input1),
        once(palchecker(Input1, Output, ToRemove)),
        string_codes(Output1, Output).

palchecker(Input, Output, ToRemove):-
  length(Input, Len),
  between(0, Len, ToRemove),
  Size is Len-ToRemove,
  length(Output, Size),
  remove_n(ToRemove, Input, Input1),
  palindrome(Output),
  permutation(Input1, Output).

remove_n(N, Input, Input2):-
  N > 0,
  succ(N1, N),
  select(_, Input, Input1),
  remove_n(N1, Input1, Input2).
remove_n(0, Input, Input).
```

The use of `once/1` is there to get only a maximal palindrome solution (there might be many solutions with the same length). The algorithm as-is would yield many repetitions of the same solution for many inputs.
I also added the number of items removed as a parameter to string2List.